# Missing a using directive or an assembly reference (ClientContext)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint

I'm trying to test this code snippet but I get the "Missing a using directive or an assembly reference" error on "ClientContext oContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);" I'm copying and pasting directly from the Microsoft site so I'm not sure what am I missing...

```
using System;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using SP = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;

namespace Microsoft.SDK.SharePointServices.Samples
{
    class BreakSecurityInheritance
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string siteUrl = "http://MyServer/sites/MySiteCollection";
            ClientContext oContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
            SP.List oList = oContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Announcements");

            oList.BreakRoleInheritance(true, false);

           oContext.ExecuteQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure you've [added a reference to the assembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.clientcontext.aspx) `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll`

Comment: Why are you Aliasing Microsoft.SharePoint.Client..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said earlier, you need a reference to the SharePoint client object model. Luckily, you can get those from Microsoft as part of the SP Client OM redistributable without having to install a full local SharePoint server.

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=21786

Answer (score 3):

First you're bringing the members of `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client` into the global scope, but right afterwards you're remapping that namespace to the `SP` alias.

That means you should qualify its members with the alias:

```
SP.ClientContext oContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
```

Or remove the aliasing and use plain `List`, but I suppose the alias is there to prevent conflicts with `List<T>` in the first place.

Comment: I replaced the line with the ones you provided, but I'm still getting the same error... Any possible solution?

Comment: Do you mean the compiler tells you it doesn't know what `SP.ClientContext` is? Can you post the exact error you receive? (you can copy it from your `Output` pane instead of retyping it from the `Errors` pane.)

Comment: It tells me "Error 1 The type or namespace name 'ClientContext' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?"

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any Query and if this is taken from the site then you are missing a Query.. otherwise you have nothing to Execute not to mention you need to do some Name resolution probably within your code.. [Here is the Link to the example he's trying to imulate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ee534956.aspx)
How To use SharePoint with C#

Mark have you actually gone to the project , right clicked on reference and select add then navigate to where the Microsoft.SharePoint.Client dll is.. are you getting a yellow icon in the project properties when you build the project..??